# power bi taking count of number

Tags: powerbi

iam taking simple clustered bar chart and want to take top 10 rows of computers that goes out of warranty
so ideally my chart should look like this

[image]

but instead my bar chart is looking like

[image]

i dont want count of count of count

[image]

can you please help me out how to add exact number in bar chart or am i taking wrong visual?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change your X via rightclick on the "Values"-Slot to something more like "Minimum", "SUM" or "Average". PowerBI doesn't seem to know you have one value only and attempts to group them. Hence it informs you that the "count of values(count)" is always one.